# IIS Redirect not working 3

Tags: iis, redirect, url-rewrite-module

Can someone explain why this rule is not working? I want a permanent redirect when the querystring below is in the url

```
<rule name="Telephony Document Lib Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)?RootFolder=%2FTechnology%2FShared%20Documents%2FTelephony(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/sites/teams/Telephony" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The querystring is separate from the url, and should be matched using a condition, like so:

```
<rule name="Telephony Document Lib Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="RootFolder=%2FTechnology%2FShared%20Documents%2FTelephony(.*)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/sites/teams/Telephony" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```